# Можно ли добавить ещё один шаблон формата Strings.ReplaceAll

Tags: golang

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    wlc := "Hello {usr}! Your age is {age}
    form := strings.ReplaceAll(wlc, "{usr}", flag.Arg(0)
    form := strings.Replace.All(wlc, "{age}", flag.Arg(1)
    fmt.Println(form)
}
```

Выводит: Hello {usr}! Your age is 19.

Нужно: Hello Mike! Your age is 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`strings.Replacer`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings#Replacer):

```golang
const wlc = `Hello {usr}!  Your age is {age}.`

flag.Parse()
var r = strings.NewReplacer(
	"{usr}", flag.Arg(0),
	"{age}", flag.Arg(1),
)

fmt.Println(r.Replace(wlc))
```